# How can i hide app icon in ActionBar?

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, action

I want to hide app icon in action bar.

My code is.........

```
.
.
.
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
.
.
.
```

[image]
I don't want this screen.

So, I added 'setDisplayShowHomeEnable()'

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

[image]
???

ActionBar position is lower than TAB.
What is this?

How can i hide APP Icon without Layout change?

Comment: see my answer below it's work perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You just change the Theme In you android Main-fest file You just **use this theme in you Application** it will not show the icon

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.activity.Mainactivity"
        android:label="Study Summary" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 
        ActionBar.SetDisplayOptions(0, ActionBarDisplayOptions.UseLogo);

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setIcon(null);
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This and it's work perfectly:

```
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```